# Is this an optimal setup for solo mining XMR?

Tags: monerod, mining, full-node

I know it's possible to solo mine XMR using XMRig through some pools, but I'd like to try to solo mining on my own, with no pools involved. As I have the intention to set up a public full node using `monerod`, I have decided to also setup some miner rigs to solo mine with the arrangement represented in the picture below.
[image: Mining arrangement proposal]
Explained:

- These 3 miners will be connecting to an internal private full node for new blocks to be mined. They will connect to the private `monerod` using the [Daemon RPC](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html) interface.
- The internal private full node will be syncing from the public one using `--add-exclusive-node` or `--add-priority-node` whichever is better. Still don't know.
- The public full node will be totally optimized for syncing with as many external nodes as possible so that generated blocks arrive as fast as possible (I still don't know how to setup for that).
- Personal wallets will connect to private full node to increase security.
- The proxy component was discarded because there are only 3 miners and I guess `monerod` is able to deal with them. I'll see...

Now my main question: Is this an optimal solution for solo mining?

Some concerns:

- As `monerod` looks a bit slow when syncing I'm not sure if it is the right tool to be used for getting new blocks to be mined.
- If `monerod` gives exactly the same jobs to all 3 miners, XMRig could end up waisting CPU by computing the same hashes in each rig. But apparently it won't happen although I'm not totally sure so I need confirmation. According to RandomX docs it looks like randomness happens for each result hash on program initialization stage (not sure now), they all use the same key (K) that RandomX gets as input together with the block data to be hashed (H), then a 1st random program is generated to get each result hash, so it is suposed that there won't be a problem getting the same data from `monerod`. Could anyone confirm this?

An improvement:

- Would it be an improvement connecting the miners to a public full node?
- Would then the security for the private full node be compromised?

Comment: I want to do the same thing. So I have setup the following: I am running a Monero node using monerod on a Ryzen 5 the blockchain has fully downloaded and up to date. I took one of my mining rigs (running xmrig) and reconfigured the Json file using the ip of the node I am running. I restarted the rig and xmrig comes back and tells me connection refused. Any suggestion to make this work would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did anyone find an excellent answer to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this an optimal solution for solo mining?

Looks reasonable.

> As `monerod` looks a bit slow when syncing...

Then make sure it has a good internet connection, fast disk (SSD) and a decent enough CPU.

> I'm not sure if it is the right tool to be used for getting new blocks to be mined.

The *only* tool right now for getting block data to be mined is `monerod`. Even if you used a pool, that pool uses `monerod`, and right now there is only one implementation of a Monero full node and that is `monerod`.

> If `monerod` gives exactly the same jobs to all 3 miners, XMRig could end up waisting CPU by computing the same hashes in each rig.

Except it doesn't. XMRig calls `get_block_template` passing in some random bytes, so the resulting block hashing blob will be *unique* to each miner.

> According to RandomX docs...

This has little to do with RandomX or the random nature of it. The *data* being hashed is *already* unique to each miner, as outlined above. If the *data* being hashed *wasn't* unique, then calling the hashing function with the *same* data will result in the *same* hash (which is how others can reproduce a hash and thus verify submitted blocks).

> Would it be an improvement connecting the miners to a public full node?

If the public node you chose to use is better maintained and configured than your own node, then yes.

> Would then the security for the private full node be compromised?

No.